# Pass value in javascript for graphs

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file with JavaScript and i have few data how can i pass those values. How can I pass those values to the graphs ?

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

// Module1 = login, Pass1=10, Fail1=2, Module2=Logout, Pass2=5, Fail2=8

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      var stepData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Module',Modulei],
          ['Pass', Passi],
          ['Fail', Faili],         
        ]);
      var options = {
      title: Modulei,
      width:500,
      height:300
    };
      var container = document.getElementById('draw-charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
      chart.draw(stepData, options);
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
        </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="draw-charts"></ul>
</body>
```

So for each graph the module name, Pass and Fail count should get replaced with the value in commented section. How can I do that ? Please help. Also let me know if we can provide the value other than commented option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your bugs now you can play around it

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('running')
        const dataRaw = [
            {Module : 'Result 1', Pass : 80, Fail  : 20},
            {Module : 'Result 2', Pass : 60, Fail  : 40},
            {Module : 'Result 3', Pass : 30, Fail  : 70}]

        google.charts.load('current',  {  packages: ['corechart'] });


        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart(){



            for(let i=0; i<3; i++){

                var data = []
                var options = {}
                data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                    ['Pass', dataRaw[i].Pass],
                    ['Fail', dataRaw[i].Fail],
                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: dataRaw[i].Module,
                    width:500,
                    height:300
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'+i));

                chart.draw(data, options);


            }

        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="piechart0" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="piechart1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="piechart2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: No, my requirement was like each graph should have a different module name. Here you have changed the values which i mentioned.  For every graph the module, Pass and Fail should be different value. also you have changed the input value names.

Comment: @wanderors first of all if you need a dynamic variable in JavaScript then you must use array or object.  Concatenation and the generation of the variable is a very bad practice. You can I have used the array of objects and hopefully, this is your desired output